# Regex/Php: Cannot match question mark in live site

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove the $_GET parameter of the first "page" item on a website.

The following works perfectly in a test script on my local server:

```
$urls = array(
'http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=1',  //should match
'http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=23',
'http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=120',
'http://www.foo.com/bar.html?baz=123&p=1'  //should match
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {

    echo $url . '<br>';

    echo preg_replace('/([\?&]p=1)(?!\d)/', '', $url) . '<p>';
}
```

This produces:

```
http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=1
http://www.foo.com/bar.html

http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=23
http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=23

http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=120
http://www.foo.com/bar.html?p=120

http://www.foo.com/bar.html?baz=123&p=1
http://www.foo.com/bar.html?baz=123
```

However on the live site, it never matches.

To make matters worse,

```
str_replace('?p=1','',$url);
```

will not work as well. What am I missing? I **can** match a single question mark, but as soon as something follows it, I'm out of luck. This is the case for both str_replace and preg_replace. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot figure it out. Thank you for your help.

**Solution:**

In my specific case, it turned out that the underlying Magento shop system was already giving out html_encoded characters. This, plus the fact the first parameter is *always* a session ID which is later removed from the URL string, made my task as easy as

```
$url = str_replace('&amp;p=1', '', $url);
```

Comment: Can you just use `parse_url` instead?

Comment: Show us `var_dump($url);` from your live site?

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: Yes, they aren't a magic wand, but with modern regex you can even correctly parse html with reasonable performance. What you're stating might be a good rule in general, but dismissing regex out of the box is a mind set from like 10 years ago. Especially with php, which is _DAMN slow_ itself, it really doesn't matter that much _most_ of the time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `parse_url()`. I still have no idea why string operations behave so weirdly on the live system, but I could solve my problem with this function

Answer (score 0):

try \\\? instead of \? ; if that doesn't work, you might run a regex engine version which doesnt support negative lookahead.

In that case you could reform your preg_replace to

`preg_replace('/([\?&]p=1)([^\d])/', '$2', $url) . '<p>';`

which would consume the non-digit, but put it back in again. There might be edge cases where this differs from your regex, but I don't think you'd be able to encounter those with urls (and I can't think of any from the top of my head)

of course, there are other non-regex solutions to this, but as regex is a very powerful tool, it's always good to learn something about it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time, griffin. However, I could not get your regex to work both live and local. I will use the parse_url approach